# Php Checkbox Undefined offset

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
$rsAppPage = $rs->SelectQuery("
Select Disabled
            from table
           ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsAppPage);
                $storeArray[] =  $row['Disabled'];  
                $str_out .= '
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Add" id="chk" data-contact_avl="val" value="1" checked='. $storeArray[0].'>Add
                <input type="checkbox" name="View" id="chk" data-contact_avl="val" value="2"  checked='. $storeArray[1]. '>View
```

I want to get the values from mysql and make the checkbox checked or not!
I have a column Disabled in database which is 0 or 1.

> I am stuck here: Undefined offset: 1,2..

Answer (score 0):

In html if you want a check a checkbox you should use

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

So what you could do is

```
if ($row['Disabled'] == 1) {
  $checked = 'checked';
} else {
  $checked = '';
}
```

Then just add the checked to html input.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="Add" id="chk" data-contact_avl="val" value="1" $checked>Add
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted `$checked = 'checked="checked"';` ?